# UseInMemoryDatabase context isn't being shared across unit tests

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, xunit

I'm using Entity Framework Core `2.0-preview1` with InMemory `2.0-preview1`.
Each unit test class inherits a disposable class that creates a new in-memory database that its parents can use.

```cs
public Constructor()
{
    var services = new ServiceCollection();

    services.AddEntityFrameworkInMemoryDatabase()
        .AddDbContext<DBContext>(o => o.UseInMemoryDatabase("Test"));

    var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

    Context = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<DBContext>();
}
```

The issue with giving the database a name is that it cannot be shared across multiple tests, and thus each test creates a new context resulting in each unit test lasting a few seconds, which is unacceptable for my build server. I can't find much documentation on why this was changed in 2.0 or how to get past this.
I've tried using the new `.UseTransientInMemoryDatabase`, but this appears to change nothing.

Comment: If you share the same db context across unit tests, how do you ensure specific pre-conditions and assert post-conditions for each test?

Comment: I do some tracking on entities added into the context and flush them out after each test, this enables me to bypass the initialization time of the database per request.

Comment: Have you tried using a static constructor?

Comment: What test framework is used?

Comment: XUnit 2.2.0-beta5-build3474.

Comment: @KieranDevlin, in xUnit a test class is re-created per each test case.

Comment: Hmm, it was working in `EF core v1.1.2`. Ill have a look at what I can do with XUnit then.

Comment: Unlikely! There is no way this can have been preserved outside of the defined test class.

Comment: Set up a fixture to provide your DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a xUnit fixture to provide all my test instances with the save database context. That way I avoid the context creation overhead on each test which speeds the build server up by a large margin.

Comment: In xUnit, to share objects across tests, we use the constructor to create the shared property available in the whole Test class.

Comment: @peter.fr A fixture was required as it wasn't just necessary for the class instance, but rather the whole namespace.